# Google Sheets: extracting numbers from multiple cells that contain text and numbers for one column of data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working in Google Sheets. I have a few hundred cells that contain text and numbers. The cells contain employee names and their ID#s. I want to extract the ID#s and compile them into one list. I have the formula below that will let me complete the task, but only for one cell, not for a range of cells (even if I select a range and add it to the formula):

`=transpose(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"\s\d+\s"," "),"[^\d\.]"," ")," "))`

For example, cell A1 would contain, "Tammy - 123456, Bob - 654987, Mike - 321456" and repeat similar until you get to something like cell DT75 "Marcus - 35768, Bruce - 95126, Lisa - 789123". Some cells in the sheet are blank. The above formula will give me the ID#s from A1 in their own cells:

123456

654987

321456

I'd like to get one column of all the ID#s in the sheet that I could then copy and paste into a completely different proprietary database. Am I coming at this the wrong way? Is a script a better angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want your original range to be multi-column, you could try a slightly modified version of [player0's formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037196), like this:

- Use [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) to put all data in a single string.
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) to remove everything but the numbers from your string.
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to divide your string into several cells, blank space being the separator.
- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) put all resulting values into a single column.

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(A:DT), "[A-Za-z-,]+", )," "))
```

[image]

Comment: This also worked. Thank you! I'm more familiar with these commands. I appreciate your walkthrough of the formula.

Comment: @RQS2020 just a reminder CONCATENATE has limited input

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[A-Za-z-,]+", ),,9^9), " ")))
```

[image]

for multi-column:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(A1:C, "[A-Za-z-,]+", ),,9^9)), " ")))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I'll have to walk through the formula to make sure I understand how all those commands are pulling the data.

Comment: @RQS2020 REGEXREPLACE will remove upper and lower characters or any - & commas [A-Za-z-,]+ so you are left out with numbers and spaces. QUERY then joines whole A1:A range into single cell. SPLIT will split it on each empty space and FLATTEN will transpose it into one column. INDEX is needed to iterate the regex on A1:A range. 9^9 means "smash all rows into one cell"